# Bluetooth barcode getInputStream()

Tags: java, android

I am using a bluetooth barcode reader to deliver text to an edit text. The problem is that it cuts the barcode text for about half the time and delivers me an incomplete text.

I am using the class "BluetoothSocket".
This is my reading code:

```
int bytes = socket.getInputStream().read(buffer);

message = message + new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

// Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
handler.post(new MessagePoster(textView, message));
```

I am looking for a way to make the action of getInputStream() be longer

Comment: Is your `buffer` large enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, just keep going until the string is the expected length. I'm assume the stream just keeps going.

```
InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
do {
    byte [] buffer = new byte[256];
    int bytes = stream.read(buffer);
    builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytes));
} while ((builder.length() < 10));
String completeStr = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to read from the `InputStream`...

```
InputStream i = socket.getInputStream();
        int c;
        String message;
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("");
        while((c=i.read())!=-1)
        {
            s.append((char)c);
        }
        message = s.toString();
```

Comment: I actually already found what i was looking for and its similar to what you present. the problem was that i didnt append strings since there were several packets in the message thx :)